# what is the best way to get professional feedback on my resume

Tags: resume

Are there standard resources online or otherwise for getting feedback on my resume?

Comment: Are companies calling you? That's all the feedback you need.

Comment: I haven't made it public yet

Comment: If you go to a head hunter or placement service they will review your resume.  But you may not want to work with head hunter or placement agency.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting feedback on your resume is pretty easy:

1. Contact the company/recruiter who may have rejected you.

"Hello, I know that you found a more suitable candidate for the position. I was hoping that you might send me some feedback on my resume, and any suggestions regarding how I presented myself in the interview. Thank you for your time, etc"

2. A lot of colleges, or hiring agencies will also provide resume proofing services, and even run mock interviews with you. Ask a fellow professional whom you get along with to take a look as well.
3. Last but not least Google is your friend :-P

---

Ted, if you've never applied with your resume before then I suggest asking someone who has a career in your field to take a look - hopefully someone who's been involved in hiring for their company. Barring that, anyone with recruiting experience will be able to give you pointers. Step #2 very much applies here.

The important thing is not to apply with a flawed resume and miss opportunities that interest you. It's easy enough to ask someone for advice. Best of luck!

Comment: Has anyone tried #1 when not given an interview and did it result in useful feedback?

Comment: @Brandin - I have done that before. The company actually sent me a couple of pretty good pointers. I think most people feel pretty good about being asked for their input/advice. Of course not everyone will bother to reply, but what can you do?

Comment: My personal experience corroborates this answer, I find that generally people are more than willing to offer you opinions and advice on your resume. It might even increase your chances in a future application to their firm since you've shown that you are able to be critical of your own work and accepting of other peoples' opinions.